# Image margin behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, image, margin

When I set my image margin in run-time it acts strange, different then when I set it via xaml code.

I want the margin value to be (40, 16, 0, 0).

When I add it in run-time, my code is this:

```
        System.Windows.Controls.Image proba = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        ImageSource imageSource = GetSlidePart(PresentationDocument.Open(path, false), 0, "rId2");
        proba.Source = imageSource;
        proba.Width = 2245721 / 9525;
        proba.Height = 2286004 / 9525;
        proba.Margin = new Thickness(40, 16, 0, 0);
        gridName.Children.Add(proba);
```

But, when I add image in xaml, the code in cs is this:

```
        image1.Source = GetSlidePart(PresentationDocument.Open(path, false), 0, "rId2");
```

and the code in xaml is this:

```
<Window x:Class="GetInfoFromPptxFile.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="720" Width="960">

<Grid Name="gridName">
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="416,20,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,16,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

When I run my program, image1 is exactly where I want it to be, and the image named proba is not. Why is this when I give them the same margin values?

Comment: We need more than this. Images of what you want and what you get. Also: what is the magic `proba.Width = 2245721 / 9525;`? It is missing in the XAML version...

Comment: The source image is the same. The height and width isn't important also, I tried setting the same width and height and the problem remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're not setting the horizontal and vertical alignments in C#.

Try adding:

```
proba.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
proba.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

and it'll look the same.